# Contacts not displaying on clicking Add button (React App)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After adding key={ contact.id} to ContactList component, contacts (name, email, and trash icon) are not visible on clicking Add button. Id (generated by uuid) is passed from ContactCard to ContactList and then to App.js. I am new to react and its concepts. There may be a tiny mistake but I am not able to figure it out.

[Here's how it should be...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXqn5.png)

[Here's how it is...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0K07l.png)

These components are going to be checked,

**App.js**

```
function App() {
const LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY = "contacts";
const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

const addContactHandler = (contact) => {
setContacts([...contacts, {id: uuid(), ...contact }]);
};

const removeContactHandler = (id) => {
const newContactList = contacts.filter((contact) => {
  return contact.id !== id;
}); setContacts(newContactList);}

useEffect(() => {
const retreiveContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY));
if(retreiveContacts) setContacts(retreiveContacts);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
localStorage.setItem(LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, JSON.stringify(contacts));
}, [contacts]);

return (
<div className="ui container">
  <Header />
  <AddContact addContactHandler = {addContactHandler}/>
  <ContactList contacts = {contacts} getContactId = {removeContactHandler}/>
</div> );}
```

**ContactList.js**

```
import React from "react";
import ContactCard from "./ContactCard";

const ContactList = (props) => {
const deleteContactHandler = (id) => {
    props.getContactId(id);
};

const renderContactList = props.contacts.map((contact) => {
    return <ContactCard 
    contact = {contact} 
    clickHandler = {deleteContactHandler} 
    key={ contact.id}/>
});

return (
<div className="ui celled list"> {renderContactList} </div> 
);};
```

**ContactCard.js**

```
const ContactCard = (props) => {
const {id, name, email} = props.contact;
return (
    <div className="item ">
        <img className="ui avatar image" src={user} alt="user" />
            <div className="content">
                <div className="header">{name}</div>
                <div>{email}</div>
            </div>
            <i className="trash alternate outline icon" 
            style={{color: "red", marginTop: "10px "}}
            onClick={() => props.clickHandler(id)}></i>
        </div>
);};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(Updated)**

The problem was the `import {uuid} from 'uuidv4';`. The right way to import this is doing:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import AddContact from './AddContact';
import ContactList from './ContactList';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
```

And the setContacts in App.js needs to be like this:

```
setContacts([...contacts, {id: uuidv4(), ...contact }]);
```

I tried here and it works!

Extra tip:

I noticed that you AddContact component could be changed to be a better class component. See some changes that you could do:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        name: "",
        email: ""
    };

    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
}

add = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(this.state.name === "" || this.state.email === ""){
        alert("All fields are mandatory");
        return;
    }

    this.props.addContactHandler(this.state);
    //clearing name and email
    this.setState({name: "", email: ""});
 
};
```

Using constructor is a better way to use props in your class component, and bind your functions to use "**this.add**" for example.

Comment: Tried, but no success

Comment: Issue can be in ContactCard also, as name and email is fetched from there.

Comment: Ok, do you have a link for a Github Repo? If you have, send here please, so I can run and understand better what is happening

Comment: @AimenAhmad Yes, can be in this component, do you tried use console log to know if the contact object is arriving in ContactCard? Or add a text in any element of ContactCard instead of props?

Comment: Thanks! I saw your project and i find what was the problem, see my updated answer and try to apply in your local project.